# Angular 4 - how to use data from Http Post Response to .js file or highchart?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, http-post

i am new to Angular 4.

I try to create dashboard, which data came from Http Post Response and i want to using data to make Chart ( Highchart ). I am success to receiving the response in the console.log and forming to array which Highchart formats needs.

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  //'use strict';
  title = 'app';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(
        data => {
        console.log("User Login: " +data.login);
        console.log("Bio: " +data.bio);
        console.log("Company: " +data.company);
    }, 
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error){
            console.log("Client-side Error occured");
        } else {
            console.log("Server-side Error occured"); 
        }
    })
    const body = {};
    const req = this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5004/meta/pushnotiflogevent',body,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    }) 
    .subscribe(data => {

          var datas: any[] = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
                datas.push(data['data'][i]['count']);
              }


    console.log(datas); 
},
        err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
        })
  }
}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//import { ChartModule } from 'angular-highcharts';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
    //ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "angular-highcharts": "^3.4.5",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "daterangepicker": "^2.1.25",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.14",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

My question is how to using data i received from console.log(datas) ?
i want passing this data to .js file or any suggestion to make highchart or chart from console.log(datas)?

any suggestion is welcome, thanks..

Comment: Please follow the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts . Please try it and come back if you have any problem using it.

Comment: Thanks @VikhyathMaiya ,i am trying now..

Comment: okay..let us know if you face any issue

Comment: angular2-highcharts is it the same when i using it in angular 4?

Comment: how are you using highcharts ??I mean did you npm install it or you are just including the js file in index.html or any other method?...You have https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts for angular 4 ass wel

Comment: i am including the js file in index.html but it still static data. i want the data which i get from Http.post console.log and passing the value to that .js file. can i do that?

Comment: You are diverting from the main concepts of angular .The way you are doing,it can be done,but you wont be using angular in any way.Please go through angular before continuing

Comment: I really want to go through angular, but how ? need help

Comment: you can go through official docs,https://angular.io/ ,or you can watch useful videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWQZCDegWHg&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6

Comment: if follow the concepts of angular, after i success get post response. what i need to prepare? and what to use? service? observable?.. thanks

Comment: actually you dont have to do anything.You have to install highchart component using npm,after the response comes modify the data in the way highchart needs and display it ..Thats it

Comment: can u please show me some sample project which step to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
     .subscribe(data => {
      let values  = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
            values.push(data['data'][i]['count']);
          }  
         let data = {
          chart: {
            type: 'column',
            options3d: {
              enabled: true,
              alpha: 12,
              beta: 0,
              depth: 50,
              viewDistance: 25
            }
          },
          credits: {
            'enabled': false
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Order Status for ' + currentyear,
            style: {
              fontSize: '8 px'
            }
          },
          xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: data.monthdetails,
            crosshair: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: '12px'
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            title: {
              text: 'Orders'
            }
           },

          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            labelFormatter: function () {
              return this.name.toString().substring(0, 2);
            },
          },
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
              stacking: 'normal',
            }
          },
          series: values
        }
```

})

Comment: i have attached a sample code which i was using iam using angular2 highcharts

Comment: this code looks great, what's dependencies or import needs to this code? how do you reference it to html page?

Comment: <section class="widget dashboard-graph-box" widget>
   <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="row">
     <chart style="width:90%" [options]="chartreport"></chart>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

Comment: you just need to install npm angular2 highcharts depends on what stable version you need the above comment i have attached to pass data in html by setting options to chartreport which i above mentioned

Comment: how about module.ts and component.ts file? are u used many files? i have try and still no success

Comment: can i take a look at the code which you are make? Angular 4 seems very hard

Comment: import {HighchartsStatic} from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import {ChartModule} from "angular2-highcharts";   
you need to above these two files in your main module .ts

Comment: may i know what is your highcharts version can u post here?

Comment: did u mean package.json ? i have try several install npm highcharts

Comment: check your highcharts version

Comment: already show my package.json, need way to make this dashboard come out from json Post response